# $G_\delta$ diagonal of countably compact space implies compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> If $X$ is countably compact, and the diagonal $\Delta$ is a $G_\delta$ set in $X\times X$, then $X$ is compact.

I have no idea where to even start with this problem. Any help in solving this is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\st}{\operatorname{st}}$That one is not easy. [Dan Ma’s Topology Blog](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/countably-compact-spaces-with-g-delta-diagonals/) has a proof. In case you’d like to try your hand at it before reading the whole proof, here are some hints.

If $\mathscr{G}$ is any family of subsets of $X$, and $x\in X$, define $$\st(x,\mathscr{G})=\bigcup\{G\in\mathscr{G}:x\in G\}\,.$$ A sequence $\langle\mathscr{G}_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ of open covers of $X$ is a $G_\delta$-*diagonal sequence* of $X$ if $\{x\}=\bigcap_{n\in\omega}\st(x,\mathscr{G}_n)$ for each $x\in X$.

**Lemma:** $X$ has a $G_\delta$-diagonal iff it has a $G_\delta$-diagonal sequence of open covers. (There’s a proof [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/11/18/compact-spaces-with-g-delta-diagonals/) if you want to read one without seeing the proof of the result on which you’re working.)

To prove your theorem, start with a $G_\delta$-diagonal sequence $\langle\mathscr{G}_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ of open covers of $X$. If $X$ is Lindelöf, we’re done, so assume that $X$ has an open cover $\mathscr{U}$ with no countable subcover. Recursively construct $x_\alpha\in X$ and $m(\alpha)\in\omega$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that

- $x_\alpha\in X\setminus\bigcup\{\st(x_\beta,\mathscr{G}_{m(\beta)}):\beta<\alpha\}$, and
- no countable subcollection of $\mathscr{U}$ covers $X\setminus\bigcup_{\beta\le\alpha}\st(x_\beta,\mathscr{G}_{m(\beta)})$.

Finally, use the fact that there must be some $n\in\omega$ such that $A=\{\alpha<\omega_1:m(\alpha)=n\}$ is uncountable. Let $D=\{x_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$; show that $D$ is uncountable, closed, and discrete to get a contradiction.